# Jar issue while deploying a war

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jar, war

well I have an application which I am building using Maven and running on eclipse(tomcat runtime) , it is working fine. But when I deploy the WAR of the project on tomcat (not using eclipse), its failing. The error is due to a coustome jar which I have included.

Stack trace are as follows:-

```
Aug 26, 2013 3:18:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in dependencyCheck
java.io.IOException: Jar: smartcharging-model.jar
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.checkManifest(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.getManifest(ExtensionValidator.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:196)
    ... 29 more

Aug 26, 2013 3:18:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Aug 26, 2013 3:18:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Smart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 26, 2013 3:18:16 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
INFO: The stop() method was called on component [WebappLoader[/Smart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have an issue , even after running all the above commands. As of now I have found an workaround where in I am deleting that JAR file from the Target deployed on the server and then again copying it. I think so manually copping the JAR solves the issue.

Comment: Can you provide configuration of maven-war-plugin from your pom.xml file? It seems, that one of jar files you've in your WEB-INF/lib is corrupted and this may be caused by incorrectly configured filtering, performed by maven-war-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
mvn clean install
```

and your code again

Comment: I have already tried it. The issues is same thing is working while I am running from eclipse but its not working otherwise

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you have a corrupted jar. Have you tried removing it from your local repository (~/.m2/repository) and

```
mvn clean package
```

again ? eclipse might not share the same repository that the one you use to build the war in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated manifest file in META-INF folder, 
make sure that `'header : value'` are in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was caused by encoding problems during the transfer of the war file from a Windows to a Unix system.

For this task I used WinSCP with the **"Standard"** file transfer option. As soon as I switched to the **"Binary"** format it worked and the war could be read by the application server.